# How to Unit or Integration Test in Python Django Models in Docker

Tags: python, django, docker, pytest

I watched this tutorial on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wxO8hRIP4w and it helped me in a way but the tutorial lacks on how to test a Django Model.

Here's the code I've got so far:

conftest.py

```
import pytest
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
import requests

@pytest.fixture(name="homepage")
def fixture_homepage(function_scoped_container_getter) -> str:
    service = function_scoped_container_getter.get('app').network_info[1]
    base_url = f"http://{service.hostname}:{service.host_port}"

    retry = Retry(
        total = 30,
        backoff_factor=10,
        status_forcelist = [500, 502, 503, 504]
    )

    session = requests.Session()
    session.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry))

    return base_url
```

first_test.py

```
from requests import get

pytest_plugins = ["docker_compose"]

def test_one():
    assert 1==1

def test_initial_ticket(homepage: str):
    print("HOMEPAGE: ", homepage)
    temp_str = get(homepage+"/admin").text

    #check if the pytest can already open the admin login page
    assert "Admin Login" in temp_str
```

When I run `pytest integration_tests/initial_user_receipt_test.py  -s`, both of the tests in first_test.py passes. I can also see that when I run this script, the docker image is built.

However, I want to test inserting to a model.py which is located in the same folder as the integration_tests folder. I have tried importing the model directly and some classes inside it but it doesn't work.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
- Project
   - integration_tests
      - conftest.py
      - first_test.py
   - apps.py
   - models.py #contains a User class
```

Comment: ` I have tried importing the model directly and some classes inside it but it doesn't work.` Can you provide more detail? What did that import code look like? What was the result? Change "it didn't work" to a description of excatly what happened, including a traceback or other output.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using pytest and not django unit tests?